# How to optimize this Python regular express for string replace?

Tags: python, regex

sql statements as below need to add in 'go' after each 1000 insert batch

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1 VALUES ('BoM001164','2008-10-01 13:39:08',...);
INSERT INTO tbl_1 VALUES ('BoM001175','2008-10-15 16:09:39',...);
...
INSERT INTO tbl_1 VALUES ('BoM001180','2008-10-02 16:06:47',...);
INSERT INTO tbl_1 VALUES ('BoM001182','2008-10-17 14:27:46',...);
```

in Python , I tried this one:

```
outString=re.sub(r'(?<=;.)(?P<Go1000>(INSERT INTO.*?;.){1000})(?=INSERT INTO)','replace':'\g<Go1000>GO\x0a',inString,flags=re.MULTILINE+re.DOTALL)
```

I killed it after 30 minutes while it's still running.

change batch size 1000 to 1(even up to 10), it took less than 1 minute to finish.
Any way to improve it, so the batch size can reach 1000?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `for` loop, one way to speed it up is to compile the RegEx first before doing the `re.sub` call:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=;.)(?P<Go1000>(INSERT INTO.*?;.){1000})(?=INSERT INTO)', re.MULTILINE+re.DOTALL)

for inString in lines:
    outString = re.sub(pattern, replacement, inString)
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Python compiles regex implicitly